# Skipping n initial years when calculating nonproprotional hazards using greg package

Tags: r, cox-regression

I'm using the package Greg to calculate nonproportional hazards. My dataset contains only subjects 65+ years old so I want to skip the first 65 years.

Here are the codes that I used:

```
apoe_s_f_ts <- timeSplitter(apoe_s_f_s,
                            by = 5,
                            time_var = "duration21yrs",
                            event_var = "censor21yrs",
                            time_offset = 65)
```

However, the codes above give the following error:

> Error in subset.data.frame(apoe_s_f, parse(text =
>   paste("duration21yrs",  :    'subset' must be logical

The range of the variable duration21yrs is 66.2-106.8.

Can anyone please explain to me what mistakes did I make?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using tibble? In the last version this should work but the Lexis function that the splitter depends on is a little picky when it comes to input and prefers a plain data.frame